# Laravel Eloquent ORM - Why do I need to call the 'parent model' before I'm able to access it's relations?

Tags: orm, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I think I might be missing a concept here so feel free to tell me what I'm doing is wrong and point me in a better direction.

I've a simple couple of models that look like this:

```php
class Customer extends Eloquent
{
    public function contacts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Contact');
    }
}

class Contact extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = "customers_contacts";
}
```

My problem happens when it comes to deleting a contact from a customer... In my controller:

```php
public function delete_contact($contact_id) 
{
    if ($contact_id > 0)
    {
        $customer = new Customer;
        Contact::find($contact_id)->delete();
        Session::flash('success', 'Contact deleted');
        return true;
    }
}
```

For some reason this wont work without the new Customer line. To me it makes sense to just be able to call the delete function of the Contact model, however if I remove my new Customer line I get an error telling me the Contact class can't be found.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you separate Contact and Customer class to it's own file?

Answer (score 0):

Ah ha, as crynobone and Surt eluded to I was trying to be tidy and had a few class definitions grouped in one file. Makes a lot of sense thinking about it.

I did some research on the PSR-0 standard and auto loading in laravel and everything is now working beautifully.

Answer (score -1):

No special reason for that to happend. Is the "Contact" model accesible (loadable) by itself?
Maybe you set Contact and Customer on the same file and Contact is not loaded because is not in the psr0?

Comment: @Matt It was an answer since it resolves the possible faults in the problem... Indeed, it does solve the question